# Combines chmod and running script in one line not working in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, chmod

Having the following Bash sequence that creates a file, changes file permissions (to be executable) and run the script I want to ***do in one line the last 2 commands***:

```
$ touch dotfiles.sh
$ chmod +x ./dotfiles.sh
$ ./dotfiles
```

**Solution 1**

I thought a possible solution is to use the **&&** operator. So `./dotfiles` will be executed only if `chmod` succeeds.

<s>But this solution is not working and bash says the file does not exists. Any idea?.</s>

<s>(not working solution)</s>

Note: `chmod` returns 0 if success. So the && is done, but fails in the second part when `./dotfiles.sh`:

```
$ chmod +x ./dotfiles.sh && ./dotfiles.sh
-bash: ./dotfiles.sh: No such file or directory
$
```

> Update: Solution 1 is correct. See my answer below to full explanation.

Comment: Does it work when you execute the commands one by one?

Comment: @Roman Yes! It works when you execute the chmod first and then the ./dotfiles. The idea is to make those in one line. Any idea?

Comment: What's the output of `touch dotfiles.sh && chmod +x ./dotfiles.sh && echo $?` ?

Comment: You have made `dotfiles.sh` executable, but you try to run `dotfiles` — that isn't going to work.  Either copy `dotfiles.sh` to `dotfiles` and make `dotfiles` executable, or run `dotfiles.sh`.

Comment: Note that if you fail to run `./dotfiles.sh`, then the chances are that you've got an error on the 'shebang' line (`#!/bin/sh` or similar).  You can get 'file not found' errors if the file named does not exist — for example, if you have `#!bin/sh`, missing a `/`.

Comment: With a shebang typo, the error would have rather been `̀bash: ./dotfiles.sh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @Kenavoz Hi! The output for that script is 0. Because everything is working. Thanks to your example, I came up with a solution to my code. I'm going to update the post ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

Solution 1 proposed was in fact working. After reading user's comments I figured out that the problem may be with the **content** of `dotfiles.sh` and not with the bash command I was asking for.

What problem I had?

In the dotfile.sh file, I included `#!/usr/bin/env bash` instead of `#!/bin/bash`. So when executing `chmod +x ./dotfiles.sh && ./dotfiles.sh` the `"No such file or directory"` problem, was referring to the `./dotfiles.sh` content and not with the "command" itself (that I thought).

Answer (score -3):

This should work.

```
chmod +x dotfiles.sh; [ $? -eq 0 ] && ./dotfiles.sh
```

Comment: It does not check that `chmod` success before `./dotfiles` execution.

Comment: Added a test for chmod success per @Kenavoz

Comment: What is the difference with `chmod +x ./dotfiles.sh && ./dotfiles.sh` that does not work for the OP ?